# App freezes for 6-10 seconds after getting contacts permission

Tags: ios, ios7, abaddressbook

I ask the user for contacts permission before going into a "import contacts" view controller. When I tap yes for the permission request, the app halts for about 5-10 seconds and then proceeds with the segue. During that frozen time, it does not allow any user interaction or anything else to progress.

**The action taken upon approval is at**

```
NSLog(@"Just authorized");

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

- (void)getAddressBookPermission:(EIConnectionsImportContactsTableViewController *)vc {
    if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
        ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
        //1
        UIAlertView *permissionDeniedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Permission Denied - We're unable to import contacts from your phone unless you provide approval."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [permissionDeniedAlert show];

    } else if (ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusAuthorized){
        //2
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
    } else { //ABAddressBookGetAuthorizationStatus() == kABAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined
        ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion(ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, nil), ^(bool granted, CFErrorRef error) {
            if (!granted){
                //4
                UIAlertView *permissionDeniedAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Permission Denied - We're unable to import contacts from your phone unless you provide approval."  delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [permissionDeniedAlert show];
                return;
            }
            NSLog(@"Just authorized");
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

Any identifiable reason for the standstill?

Comment: The `ABAddressBookRequestAccessWithCompletion` completion handler may not run on the main thread. You need to be sure to do all of the UI updated on the main thread.

Comment: How can I force it to use the main thread?

Comment: rmaddy thanks for the link